# Cannot import psycopg2 inside jupyter notebook but can in python3 console

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, conda

I can import pyscopg2 in my python console but not in my jupyter notebook.

I installed `psycopg2` through the anaconda-navigator.

**Jupyter notebook:**

```
import psycopg2
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-7d2da0a5d979> in <module>
----> 1 import psycopg2

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

```
import sys
sys.path
```

> ['/Users/me/Anaconda/MLJSONs', 
>   '/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python37.zip', 
>   '/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.7', 
>   '/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',  '', 
>   '/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages', 
>   '/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aeosa', 
>   '/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
>   '/Users/me/.ipython']

**Python console:**

> python3

```
>>> import psycopg2
```

No problem here.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
```

> ['', '/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/env3/lib/python37.zip',
>   '/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/env3/lib/python3.7',
>   '/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/env3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
>   '/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/env3/lib/python3.7/site-packages']

**Conda list:**

```
# packages in environment at /usr/local/anaconda3/envs/env3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  
...
psycopg2                  2.7.6.1          py37ha12b0ac_0  
python                    3.7.3                h359304d_0  
...
```

**I tried:**

Adding it to `sys.path` but the same result is occuring.

```
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/env3/lib')
```

Comment: How did you install it with what command ? (Just making sure the official docs say the following               conda install -c anaconda psycopg2                           https://anaconda.org/anaconda/psycopg2

Comment: I used the GUI in `https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/`. But I also tried `conda install -c anaconda psycopg2`.

Comment: It would have been helpful to show us the output from `psycopg2.__spec__`, which would tells us where it gets loaded from in the console case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to just install with pip outside my virtual conda environments.

```
pip install psycopg2
```

Comment: Thanks - very odd but same thing happened to me and only with this module.

Comment: In a Jupyter notebook cell, `!pip install psycopg2-binary` worked for installing psycopg2.

Comment: Installing `psycopg2` outside my venv also worked for me, but I still don't understand why I had to do that given that I started my jupyter server after activating my venv.

Comment: I don't know why, but it works. Really eager to know the reason. Besides, what singhj mentioned not work for me.

Comment: Thank you @singhj for `!pip install psycopg2-binary`!